# Displaying only 3 day of a week view of fullcalendar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar.io React component in my project for all calendar use cases. Is there any way to display only 3 days instead of all days of the week? I have tried using views attribute but it didn't work.

```
<FullCalendar 
           plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin , timeGridPlugin]}
           views = {{
            agendaThreeDay: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: { days: 3 },
                buttonText: '3 day'
            }
            }}
           selectable
           initialView = {agendaThreeDay}
       />
```

Comment: can you pass `duration=  { days: 4 }` and check ? as another prop

Comment: "agenda" isn't a view type...try `type: "timeGrid"` instead.

Comment: @Amruth why would you set 4 days duration to get a 3 day view?? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @ADyson oops my bad. i copied from document, its `duration=  { days: 3 }`

Comment: @Amruth are you trying to say that OP should use the React plugin syntax to declare this option? You may well be right but it would involve changing more than just that one : to =.

Comment: i was referring to this document -> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration `Dynamically Setting`

Comment: @Amruth ok but all you changed in your example is `:` to `=` which is nothing to do with that documentation, but would be relevant according to the react-specific general syntax shown at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react - however, more changes would be needed to comply with that

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved by changing the way `agendaThreeDay` view is used in initial view.

```
<FullCalendar 
       plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin , timeGridPlugin]}
       views = {{
        agendaThreeDay: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 3 },
            buttonText: '3 day'
        }
        }}
       selectable
       initialView = 'agendaThreeDay'
   />
```